# Issue with CAS on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: java, tomcat, ubuntu, tomcat6, cas

I setup a CAS 3.5.5 server with Ubuntu 12.04 and Tomcat6
We have a Active Directory Server with LDAPS it does not allow anonymous searches. I use the deployerConfigContext.xml listed below. When I try to Authenticate I get the following message:

> CAS is Unavailable
>   There was an error trying to complete your request. Please notify your support desk or try again.

Here is the Logs:

```
Mar 17, 2014 9:58:02 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol pause
INFO: Pausing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Mar 17, 2014 9:58:02 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol pause
INFO: Pausing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8443
Mar 17, 2014 9:58:03 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stop
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
2014-03-17 09:58:03,166 INFO [org.jasig.cas.util.AutowiringSchedulerFactoryBean] - <Shutting down Quartz Scheduler>
Mar 17, 2014 9:58:03 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol destroy
INFO: Stopping Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Mar 17, 2014 9:58:03 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol destroy
INFO: Stopping Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8443
Mar 17, 2014 9:58:04 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat6/server/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Mar 17, 2014 9:58:04 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat6/server], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Mar 17, 2014 9:58:04 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat6/shared/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Mar 17, 2014 9:58:04 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat6/shared], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Mar 17, 2014 9:58:05 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Mar 17, 2014 9:58:05 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8443
Mar 17, 2014 9:58:05 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 952 ms
Mar 17, 2014 9:58:05 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Mar 17, 2014 9:58:05 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.35
Mar 17, 2014 9:58:05 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor ROOT.xml
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: cas.log (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.openAppend(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:210)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:131)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:290)
    at org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.setFile(RollingFileAppender.java:194)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:164)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:257)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:133)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:97)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:689)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:647)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configureRootCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:544)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:440)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:476)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:471)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:125)
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:105)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.getLogger(Log4JLogger.java:289)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.<init>(Log4JLogger.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:534)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.createLogFromClass(LogFactoryImpl.java:1116)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.discoverLogImplementation(LogFactoryImpl.java:914)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:604)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:336)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:310)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:685)
    at org.jasig.cas.web.init.SafeContextLoaderListener.<init>(SafeContextLoaderListener.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:534)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:675)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: cas.log (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.openAppend(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:210)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:131)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:290)
    at org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.setFile(RollingFileAppender.java:194)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:164)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:257)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:133)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:97)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:689)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:647)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configureRootCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:544)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:440)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:476)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:354)
    at org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer.initLogging(Log4jConfigurer.java:73)
    at org.springframework.web.util.Log4jWebConfigurer.initLogging(Log4jWebConfigurer.java:152)
    at org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener.contextInitialized(Log4jConfigListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:675)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
2014-03-17 09:58:07,545 INFO [org.jasig.cas.services.DefaultServicesManagerImpl] - <Loaded 0 services.>
2014-03-17 09:58:07,751 INFO [org.jasig.cas.util.AutowiringSchedulerFactoryBean] - <Starting Quartz Scheduler now>
2014-03-17 09:58:08,346 INFO [org.jasig.cas.web.flow.AuthenticationViaFormAction] - <FormObjectClass not set.  Using default class of org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.UsernamePasswordCredentials with formObjectName credentials and validator org.jasig.cas.validation.UsernamePasswordCredentialsValidator.>
Mar 17, 2014 9:58:08 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Mar 17, 2014 9:58:08 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8443
Mar 17, 2014 9:58:08 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 2764 ms
```

deployerConfigContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
    | deployerConfigContext.xml centralizes into one file some of the declarative configuration that
    | all CAS deployers will need to modify.
    |
    | This file declares some of the Spring-managed JavaBeans that make up a CAS deployment.  
    | The beans declared in this file are instantiated at context initialization time by the Spring 
    | ContextLoaderListener declared in web.xml.  It finds this file because this
    | file is among those declared in the context parameter "contextConfigLocation".
    |
    | By far the most common change you will need to make in this file is to change the last bean
    | declaration to replace the default SimpleTestUsernamePasswordAuthenticationHandler with
    | one implementing your approach for authenticating usernames and passwords.
    +-->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">
    <!--
        | This bean declares our AuthenticationManager.  The CentralAuthenticationService service bean
        | declared in applicationContext.xml picks up this AuthenticationManager by reference to its id, 
        | "authenticationManager".  Most deployers will be able to use the default AuthenticationManager
        | implementation and so do not need to change the class of this bean.  We include the whole
        | AuthenticationManager here in the userConfigContext.xml so that you can see the things you will
        | need to change in context.
        +-->
    <bean id="authenticationManager"
        class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.AuthenticationManagerImpl">
        <!--
            | This is the List of CredentialToPrincipalResolvers that identify what Principal is trying to authenticate.
            | The AuthenticationManagerImpl considers them in order, finding a CredentialToPrincipalResolver which 
            | supports the presented credentials.
            |
            | AuthenticationManagerImpl uses these resolvers for two purposes.  First, it uses them to identify the Principal
            | attempting to authenticate to CAS /login .  In the default configuration, it is the DefaultCredentialsToPrincipalResolver
            | that fills this role.  If you are using some other kind of credentials than UsernamePasswordCredentials, you will need to replace
            | DefaultCredentialsToPrincipalResolver with a CredentialsToPrincipalResolver that supports the credentials you are
            | using.
            |
            | Second, AuthenticationManagerImpl uses these resolvers to identify a service requesting a proxy granting ticket. 
            | In the default configuration, it is the HttpBasedServiceCredentialsToPrincipalResolver that serves this purpose. 
            | You will need to change this list if you are identifying services by something more or other than their callback URL.
            +-->
        <property name="credentialsToPrincipalResolvers">
            <list>
                <!--
                    | UsernamePasswordCredentialsToPrincipalResolver supports the UsernamePasswordCredentials that we use for /login 
                    | by default and produces SimplePrincipal instances conveying the username from the credentials.
                    | 
                    | If you've changed your LoginFormAction to use credentials other than UsernamePasswordCredentials then you will also
                    | need to change this bean declaration (or add additional declarations) to declare a CredentialsToPrincipalResolver that supports the
                    | Credentials you are using.
                    +-->
                <bean
                    class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.UsernamePasswordCredentialsToPrincipalResolver" />
                <!--
                    | HttpBasedServiceCredentialsToPrincipalResolver supports HttpBasedCredentials.  It supports the CAS 2.0 approach of
                    | authenticating services by SSL callback, extracting the callback URL from the Credentials and representing it as a
                    | SimpleService identified by that callback URL.
                    |
                    | If you are representing services by something more or other than an HTTPS URL whereat they are able to
                    | receive a proxy callback, you will need to change this bean declaration (or add additional declarations).
                    +-->
                <bean
                    class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.HttpBasedServiceCredentialsToPrincipalResolver" />
            </list>
        </property>

        <!--
            | Whereas CredentialsToPrincipalResolvers identify who it is some Credentials might authenticate, 
            | AuthenticationHandlers actually authenticate credentials.  Here we declare the AuthenticationHandlers that
            | authenticate the Principals that the CredentialsToPrincipalResolvers identified.  CAS will try these handlers in turn
            | until it finds one that both supports the Credentials presented and succeeds in authenticating.
            +-->
        <property name="authenticationHandlers">
            <list>
                <!--
                    | This is the authentication handler that authenticates services by means of callback via SSL, thereby validating
                    | a server side SSL certificate.
                    +-->
                <bean class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.handler.support.HttpBasedServiceCredentialsAuthenticationHandler"
                    p:httpClient-ref="httpClient" />
                <!--
                    | This is the authentication handler declaration that every CAS deployer will need to change before deploying CAS 
                    | into production.  The default SimpleTestUsernamePasswordAuthenticationHandler authenticates UsernamePasswordCredentials
                    | where the username equals the password.  You will need to replace this with an AuthenticationHandler that implements your
                    | local authentication strategy.  You might accomplish this by coding a new such handler and declaring
                    | edu.someschool.its.cas.MySpecialHandler here, or you might use one of the handlers provided in the adaptors modules.
                    +-->
                <!-- LDAP bind Authentication Handler -->
<bean class="org.jasig.cas.adaptors.ldap.BindLdapAuthenticationHandler">
<property name="filter" value="sAMAccountName=%u" />
    <property name="searchBase" value="dc=garr,dc=org" />
    <property name="contextSource" ref="LDAPcontextSource" />
    <property name="ignorePartialResultException" value="yes" /> <!-- fix because of how AD returns results -->
</bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <!--
    This bean defines the security roles for the Services Management application.  Simple deployments can use the in-memory version.
    More robust deployments will want to use another option, such as the Jdbc version.

    The name of this should remain "userDetailsService" in order for Acegi to find it. 

    To use this, you should add an entry similar to the following between the two value tags:
    battags=notused,ROLE_ADMIN

    where battags is the username you want to grant access to.  You can put one entry per line.
     -->    
    <bean id="userDetailsService" class="org.springframework.security.userdetails.memory.InMemoryDaoImpl">
        <property name="userMap">
            <value>

            </value>
        </property>
    </bean> 

    <!-- 
    Bean that defines the attributes that a service may return.  This example uses the Stub/Mock version.  A real implementation
    may go against a database or LDAP server.  The id should remain "attributeRepository" though.
     -->
    <bean id="attributeRepository"
        class="org.jasig.services.persondir.support.StubPersonAttributeDao">
        <property name="backingMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="uid" value="uid" />
                <entry key="eduPersonAffiliation" value="eduPersonAffiliation" /> 
                <entry key="groupMembership" value="groupMembership" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- 
    Sample, in-memory data store for the ServiceRegistry. A real implementation
    would probably want to replace this with the JPA-backed ServiceRegistry DAO
    The name of this bean should remain "serviceRegistryDao".
     -->
    <bean
        id="serviceRegistryDao"
        class="org.jasig.cas.services.InMemoryServiceRegistryDaoImpl" />


        <bean id="LDAPcontextSource" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource">
    <property name="pooled" value="false"/>
    <property name="urls">
        <list>
            <value>ldap://garrmail/</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="userDn" value="uid=administrator,cn=users,dc=garr,dc=org"/>
    <property name="password" value="cuca01"/>
    <property name="baseEnvironmentProperties">
        <map>
            <entry>
                <key>
                    <value>java.naming.security.authentication</value>
                </key>
                <value>simple</value>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

I am truly at a loss!
Thanks!
Riley

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention what Version of CAS I am running!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like CAS isn't able to access the log file. What user is Tomcat running as? Does this user have write access to cas.log, and can it access the directory containing this file?

You may need to chown & chmod as appropriate.